# How do I restore the default way cells and output appears in jupyter-lab, currently they are appearing side by side?

Tags: jupyter, jupyter-lab

The cells and their output are appearing side by side instead of the default vertical setting. How do I restore this to the previous setting?

I have only been able to increase and decrease the width of the cells so far

Comment: Sounds like you activated `View > Render Side-by-Side` in the newer JupyterLab? Under `View` on the menubar there should be a way to untoggle it. That is at least how you do it in [JupyterLab version 3.30](https://mybinder.org/v2/gist/fcollonval/facfadcd926621a84556a040aac71a8f/HEAD). In that version, the setting you adjust in 'Settings' got renamed if you are looking for that; see 'breaking changes' at the bottom of [this post](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/jupyterlab-3-3-0-is-released/13231#breaking-changes-13). You now want `renderingLayout: default`.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you accidently activated `Render Side-by-Side` in jupyterlab. You can go back to its default view by press `Shift+R`

or

Go to  `View > Render Side-by-Side` and click it.